# In AngularJS, which modules can override constants?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm learning patterns from the angular-ui code. They commonly define default options as a constant on a component-specific module like this:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.buttons', [])
.constant('buttonConfig', {
  activeClass: 'active',
  toggleEvent: 'click'
})
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/buttons/buttons.js#L3

Is this a pattern I can override using a constant in a containing module?

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.buttons']).constant('buttonConfig',{
  activeClass: 'selected'
});
```

If not, I don't see a ton of use in this pattern and want to understand why they use it. For accordion, the extending of the constant requires a lot of code:

```
 var closeOthers = angular.isDefined($attrs.closeOthers) ? $scope.$eval($attrs.closeOthers) : accordionConfig.closeOthers;
```

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js#L14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can override the constant in containing module. As a matter of fact, you can override anything in the containing module.. that's how modules work in Angular.

Here's a small [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4XBdC/).

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['specific']),
    specificApp = angular.module('specific', []);

app.constant('active', {from: 'app'});
specificApp.constant('active', {from: 'specific'});

app.controller('AppCntrl', function($scope, active) {
    console.log('from AppCntrl: '+active.from); // displays 'app'
});

specificApp.controller('SpecificAppCtrl', function($scope, active) {
    console.log('from SpecificAppCtrl: '+active.from); // displays 'app'
});
```

Comment: Oooo. Case #2 suprises me. This is because the config phase for all modules execute before the run phase for any module?

Comment: I am not quite sure on that.. sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you inject the constant into your module's config function, you should be able to set whatever properties of the object you want. For example:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.buttons']).config(["buttonConfig", function (buttonConfig) {
  buttonConfig.activeClass: 'selected'
}]);
```

If you simply redefine the constant, you would be getting rid of the other properties on that constant's object (toggleEvent would no longer be available in your case). Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLHxt/1/) I put together to demonstrate the ability to change the activeClass property of a constant object from "active" to "selected".

The line:

```
var closeOthers = angular.isDefined($attrs.closeOthers) ? $scope.$eval($attrs.closeOthers) : accordionConfig.closeOthers;
```

isn't extending the constant, but rather overriding it. This is saying that if the close-others attribute was put onto the directive than use that, else revert to what was defined in the constant. By using the constant in the config, you can set default values that would be used if these attributes were left off the directives.

Comment: I see. That's very clear, thanks. It would be nice if `.constant` and `.value` supported an extend instead of replace objects at the same key.